# Sentiments analysis with ML

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, svm, sentiment-analysis

hello am trying to train a model to use it to predict some news sentiments in my project but am stuck cause i only get a accuracy of 58%, i have already tried 2 different ML algorithms still the same percentage i would love to have some advices to enhance my accuracy

here is my code below please fell free to share with me tips am new in this domain :

```
#representation with word2vec model
model_headline= Word2Vec(sentences=all_headlines_clr, vector_size= 300, min_count= 5, window=5, sg=1 )

#vectorization
vectors=[]
for headline in all_headlines_clr :
  headline_vector = [model_headline.wv[word] for word in headline
                             if word in model_headline.wv.key_to_index ]
  vectors.append(headline_vector)

#normilization
max_length = max(len(headline_vector) for headline_vector in vectors)
x_normalized = [headline_vector/ np.linalg.norm(headline_vector) for headline_vector in vectors]
x_padded= pad_sequences(x_normalized, maxlen= max_length, padding='post')
print(x_padded.shape)
x=np.array(x_padded)


x_padded_flat = x_padded.reshape(x_padded.shape[0], -1)
#buiding model
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
labels_numeric= label_encoder.fit_transform(etiquettes)
x_train, x_test,y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x_padded_flat, labels_numeric, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

rf_model= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state= 42)
rf_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = rf_model.predict(x_test)
accuracy= accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print('prediction : {:.2F}%'.format(accuracy* 100))
```

Comment: @Harshad Patil thank am checking it now. i'm a newbie please is there something i can enhance in my code or write it a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Tune your model. For example. Increase n_estimators, increase max_depth value.
Try using libraries like:

https://optuna.org/ OR https://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/

A lot of things can be done to tune the model.
Also make sure that you are not overfitting or underfitting.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this...

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# Step 1: Load and preprocess the dataset
data = pd.read_csv('sentiment_data.csv') # whatever your data is...
X = data['text']
y = data['label']

# Step 2: Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Step 3: Feature extraction
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_train_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_features = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

# Step 4: Model training
model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(X_train_features, y_train)

# Step 5: Model evaluation
accuracy = model.score(X_test_features, y_test)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)

# Step 6: Predict sentiment for new text
new_text = ["I love this product!"]
new_text_features = vectorizer.transform(new_text)
prediction = model.predict(new_text_features)
print("Predicted sentiment:", prediction[0])
```

In this example, we assume that you have a dataset called 'sentiment_data.csv' with two columns: 'text' (containing the text data) and 'label' (containing the corresponding sentiment labels). You'll need to replace 'sentiment_data.csv' with your own dataset or modify the code accordingly.

The code uses the CountVectorizer class from scikit-learn to convert the text data into a numerical representation. It then splits the dataset into training and testing sets using the train_test_split function. The Naive Bayes algorithm (implemented as MultinomialNB) is trained on the training set and evaluated on the testing set.

Finally, the trained model is used to predict the sentiment of a new text ("I love this product!") by transforming it into the same feature representation as the training data and calling the predict method.

Note that this is just a basic example, and there are many ways to improve the performance of sentiment analysis models, such as using more sophisticated feature representations (e.g., TF-IDF) or exploring different ML algorithms or deep learning approaches.